# Подскажите как правильно парсить pdf в sql

Tags: sql, база-данных, pdf, парсер

Добрый день.
Сложилась такая проблема: дали мне задачу конвертировать из pdf-таблицы(очень большой) в БД(MySQL).

Пытался конвертировать через различные онлайн-сервисы в удобный формат excel'я, дабы оттуда перевести в sql, но очень много необходимых данных попросту стирается.

Кое-как получилось конвертировать через OneDrive в xlsx, но встала еще одна проблема: все данные отображались как на pdf-файле(на каждой странице отображаются номера столбцов).

В принципе, полагаю, что это можно исправить используя VBA, но, возможно более умное сообщество SOF подскажет как это можно сделать по иному.

P.S. Может кто-нибудь подскажет скрипт на Java. А то я пока еще приходящий в IT-сферу человек и в других ЯП особо не разбираюсь.

Спасибо за оказанное внимание!. [image: Номера столбцов на каждой новой странице]

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю Java. Но скорее всего примерно то же можно реализовать и на этом языке. Я бы попытался разными конвертерами перевести в html (в excel бы не стал хотя бы из-за тяжести файла). Если бы получилось, то используя php(ф-ция explode) попробовал получить массив элементов, разбив html-текст на строки. А строки на ячейки. Судя по картинке, очевидно, что база должна содержать, как минимум две таблицы - элементы и категории (напр. амидосульфурон). Таким образом, далее, я бы совершил обход строк и в зависимости от того: 1)содержит ли строка хотя бы одну не пустую ячейку (если нет - не записываем в базу) или 2)содержит только одну ячейку (скорее всего категория) или 3)более одной непустой ячейки мог предполагать о том, в какую именно таблицу отнести данные этой строки.

Но это - просто первое, что пришло в голову. Была бы таблица, можно было бы поэкспериментировать...